# Liberty ignoring .class file while server start

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I am getting exception while running Liberty server .
javax.ejb.CreateException
[ERROR] An exception occured during processing of the com.lalit.job.servlets.TopFuncutionalityWS.
This class is ignored

I have 7 other servlets along with TopFuncutionalityWS. Other than this class all other servlets are loading residing in same folder.
I have cross checked the presence of .class file for class which is not getting loaded but that is present.

Comment: `javax.ejb.CreateException` suggests exception while creating EJB, provide full stack trace as this is not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hit and trial I got the solution for this issue. 
I was using `<enterpriseApplication>` tag for the my application in this tag I was using the property type="ear" .On removing this type property I get rid of this issue an server stopped throwing the mentioned error.

```
**<enterpriseApplication     type="ear"/>**
```